# Confusion using a complex line integral to find the area of a circle

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm trying to understand the complex line integral equation as given in [these notes](https://math.mit.edu/~jorloff/18.04/notes/topic3.pdf).  It's given as

$$\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) dt$$

where $\gamma(t)$ is a paremeterization of the curve $\gamma$ with $t \in [a, b]$.

For the purposes of understanding the math, I'm trying to use it to find the area of a circle of radius $r$ centered at the origin using the paramerization $\gamma(t) = r e^{it}$.

Intuitively I would expect the area of the circle to be the sum of the area of the triangles with altitude $|z|$ and width $dz$.

However, I end up with $0$:

$$ \int_\gamma f(z) dz = \int_\gamma \frac{1}{2}|z| dz =
\\ \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{2\pi} |r e^{it}| r i e^{it} dt =
\\ \frac{1}{2} r^2 i \int_0^{2\pi} |e^{it}| e^{it} dt =
\\ \frac{1}{2} r^2 i \int_0^{2\pi} e^{it} dt =
\\ \frac{1}{2} r^2 i \cdot 0 = 0$$

Obviously the area of a cirle isn't $0$.  What am I doing wrong?

### Edit:

By way of comparison, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the line integral is expressed as

$$ \int_C f(x) ds = \int_a^b f(x(t)) \cdot |x'(t)| dt$$

where $x(t)$ is an arbitrariy parameterization of $C$ and $t \in [a, b]$.

With the same logic as above, if we let $f(x) = |x|$ and $x(t) = <r\cos(t), r\sin(t)>$ we get:

$$ \int_a^b f(r(t)) \cdot |r'(t)| dt
\\ = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2} |\sqrt{r^2 \cos^2(t) + r^2 \sin^2(t)}| \cdot |\sqrt{r^2 (-\sin(t))^2 + cos^2(t)}| dt
\\ = \frac{1}{2} r^2 \int_0^{2\pi} |1| \cdot |1| dt
\\ = \frac{1}{2} r^2 (2 \pi - 0)
\\ = \pi r^2$$

Which is correct for the area of a circle.

I don't understand why this rough idea seems to work in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and not in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Loobear23 - I'm not sure if it does, but intuitively $|r|dr$ is the area of a rectangle of height $|r|$ and width $dr$, so summing (ie: integrating) these rectangles around the circle should give the area.  Entirely possible I'm misunderstanding something here, though, and my intuition is wrong.

Comment: $dr \ne dz$ but indeed $dr=|dz|$ so using your intuition you get the right answer using polar coordinates but it is them a double integral, not a line integral

Comment: @Conrad - I've updated the question to hopefully make clearer what I'm misunderstanding

Comment: you use the wrong measure here as $dz$ is a complex measure and it is not suited to computations of lengths or areas directly (you need to use Green theorem); the right measure is the arclength one $|dz|=rdt$ and then the reasoning works - $dz$ is a complex number so it is not a width but $|dz|$ which is a positive real number is indeed

Comment: @Conrad - Can you explain why this works in $\mathbb{R}^2$, though?  I don't doubt that you need Green's theorem in $\mathbb{C}$ but I don't see why you can just do this naive line integral in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then.  Normally $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are two sides of the same coin.

Comment: you use $|x'|dt$ and that again is a positive number - the problem is not the concept (complex vs real two dimensions) but the fact that area is indeed heightxwidth and $dz$ is not width as it has phase (so you turn around and of course get zero on a full $360$ turn) but its modulus $|dz|$ is a width

Answer (score 1):

The correct formula is that the (oriented) area of the domain (circle here) enclosed by (simple rectifiable Jordan) $\gamma$ is $\frac{1}{2i}\int_{\gamma}\bar w dw=\frac{1}{2i}\int_0^{2\pi}re^{-it}ire^{it}dt=\pi r^2$ so we are good

(here by abuse of notation $\gamma=w$ of course so if you want the integrand is $\bar \gamma \gamma'$)

Comment: Is this Green's Theorem translated to complex line integrals?

Comment: @Maximilian yes it is - one can use other line integrals like $udv, vdu$ where $\gamma =w=u+iv$ etc with appropriate coefficients but the above is the most useful in the complex analytic context in my experience

Comment: Can you explain why the area is given by $\frac{1}{2i}\int_{\gamma}\bar w dw$?

Comment: it is Green's theorem - see below (last paragraph) for an area expression involving $udv, vdu$ and then just note that $\bar w=u-iv, dw=du+idv$ and the line integrals $udu, vdv$ are zero by Green again so only the mixed terms remain https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem